# Scroll down functionality in RSS reader like Google Reader

Tags: java, rss, google-reader, rss-reader

I have implemented a simple RSS reader in Java. I hit a URL and I get back some XML text. I parse it and retrieve data that I'm interested in.
Now I want to implement what Google Reader is doing. It has a functionality by which we can scroll down and see old posts. How can I get these old posts as what I see is every time I hit the URL I get the same XML back?

Comment: Can you share the URL you are hitting? Also, are you saying that you are only seeing latest news(item) on the feed?

Comment: Yes. I'm seeing only latest items. But is there any way to get old items? As pointed out by Cello in the answer below I guess Google hits the URL more often to get more items.

Comment: I forgot to mention the URL. Here it is: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/trailers/uploads?v=2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google hits the rss links much more often than you read it, and stores all the articles in a database. So when you read it and you scroll down in Google Reader, it actually shows you all the articles it stored in the database. The RSS url is kind of only used by Google Reader to fill its database, but not directly for the display.

Comment: Thanks. So under the hood, Google is doing much more than you think. I'll implement similar feature in my simple RSS reader.

Comment: At the same time I am trying to see if I can access all the feeds (latest and old) by using API from Google Reader. Any pointer in that regard? Or should I put this as a new question?

Comment: Like @cello mentioned all the RSS feed content are pre cached in regular intervals and stored in DB ... So you'll get latest, old feeds at any given time...